# Event Bubbling, and Stop Propagation

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, event-bubbling, event-propagation

What is the difference between  `event.bubbles` to `false` for any event, and setting `event.stopPropagation()` or `stopImmediatePropagation()` while handling event?

I'm using Flex4 with AS3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Setting [`bubbles`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#bubbles) to `false` means the event does not bubble up the display list at all.

[`stopPropagation()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopPropagation()) and [`stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation()) make the current event listener the last to process an event.

The difference between `stopPropagation()` and `stopImmediatePropagation()` is that `stopImmediatePropagation()` will not only prevent the event from moving to the next node, but it will also prevent any other listeners on that node from capturing their events.

Answer (score 32):

Information found at this article - [Introduction to event handling in ActionScript 3.0](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html) is more demonstrative and easy to understand. It will enhance the above accepted answer by @Jason Sturges.

Event bubbling and event capturing are two faces of events. If you make the event.bubbles to false that means the event is marked as non-bubbling event.

> **bubbles**: Indicates whether or not the event is an event that bubbles (and captures). This does not mean that the event went through or is going through a capture or bubbles phase, but rather it is a kind of event that can.

Below image (from the above article) shows how the event goes through the process.

[image: Event capturing and bubbling]

The difference of the `stopPropagation()` and `stopImmediatePropagation()` will be more clear in following images.

**StopPropagation :**

[image: stopPropagation]

**StopImmidiatePropagation :**

[image: stopImmediatePropagation]

Comment: Good answer and the source is Adobe. The accepted answer didn't help at all :/

Comment: @BattleCity `The accepted answer didn't help at all :/` still got 10 upvotes? ;) He answered same day when needed.
This also good answer I upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the example:

```
object.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, functionOne );

object.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, functionTwo );
```

If `functionOne` contains `event.stopPropagation()`, `functionTwo` will be called as well. 
If it contains `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, `functionTwo` will be ignored.