# current target mouse event not registering.

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, target, flash-cs6

Hey guys so I have a Movie clip called `startScreen` on this start screen is another movie clip called `mcOptions`and within the mcOptions are buttons you can click on to choose your option. I want to be able to click on the nested buttons but nothing is registering. Here is how I have it setup:

```
startScreen.mcOptions.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTap);

private function onTap(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        if (e.currentTarget == startScreen.mcOptions.mcPlay )
        {
            trace("PLAY OPTION TRUE");
        }else
        if (e.currentTarget == startScreen.mcOptions.mcStore )
        {
            trace("PLAY OPTION TRUE");
        }else
    }
```

Nothing is ever traced. Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: before those If/Else statements try adding `trace("target is : " + e.currentTarget);` and `trace("target name is : " + e.currentTarget.name);` and see if that's useful to make a working If/Else.

Answer (score 0):

Untested (no AS3 compiler here) but you can try :

```
startScreen.mcOptions.mcPlay.name = "mc_Play";
startScreen.mcOptions.mcStore.name = "mc_Store";

startScreen.mcOptions.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTap);

private function onTap(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if (e.currentTarget.name == "mc_Play" )
    {
        trace("PLAY OPTION TRUE");
    }
    else if (e.currentTarget.name == "mc_Store" )
    {
        trace("PLAY OPTION TRUE");
    }
}
```

Also `e.currentTarget` might work better if you set as `e.target.currentTarget` (whether in your original code or my version).

Answer (score 0):

Mouse event is a bubbling event (read here: [Event Bubbling, and Stop Propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802601/event-bubbling-and-stop-propagation)) so **e.currentTarget** and **e.target** could be different objects. The property **e.currentTarget** will **ALWAYS** point to the object you subscribed your method to, in your case - **startScreen.mcOptions**. If you want to collect events from different objects at one bottleneck container, you should use **e.target** to know which is which.

Keep in mind that **e.target** will be the most deep mouse-enabled display object to fire the mouse event: either **SimpleButton** or **TextField**, or **Sprite** or **MovieClip** or any other **InteractiveObject** with **mouseChildren** property set to **false**.

```
startScreen.mcOptions.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTap);

private function onTap(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    trace("Event from:", e.target, e.target.name);

    switch (e.target.name)
    {
        case "mcPlay":
            trace("PLAY OPTION TRUE");
            break;

        case "mcStore":
            trace("STORE OPTION TRUE");
            break;
    }
}
```

**UPD:** I composed this to answer another question, but it works as you want your code to work as well. I don't know exactly what's wrong with your case for I wasn't wrong with the theory.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Snap extends Sprite
    {
        private var Circus:Vector.<Sprite>;
        private var Dots:Vector.<Point>;

        public function Snap() 
        {
            Dots = new Vector.<Point>;
            Circus = new Vector.<Sprite>;

            // Create snap points, put them on stage and keep their coordinates.
            for (var i:int = 1; i * 100 < stage.stageWidth; i++)
            {
                for (var j:int = 1; j * 100 < stage.stageHeight; j++)
                {
                    var aDot:Sprite = new Sprite;
                    var aPos:Point = new Point(i * 100, j * 100);

                    aDot.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.3);
                    aDot.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 4);
                    aDot.x = aPos.x;
                    aDot.y = aPos.y;

                    addChild(aDot);
                    Dots.push(aPos);
                }
            }

            var aCircas:int = 2 + 3 * Math.random();

            // Add random number of draggable objects.
            while (Circus.length < aCircas)
            {
                Circus.push(addCirca());
            }

            // Hook the mouse interaction.
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
        }

        // This method adds a draggable circle of random radius, color, position.
        private function addCirca():Sprite
        {
            var result:Sprite = new Sprite;

            result.name = "Circa";

            result.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0);
            result.graphics.beginFill(0x1000000 * Math.random(), 0.5);
            result.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20 + 20 * Math.random());

            result.x = stage.stageWidth * Math.random();
            result.y = stage.stageHeight * Math.random();

            addChild(result);

            result.buttonMode = true;
            result.useHandCursor = true;

            return result;
        }

        // *** DRAGGING AN ITEM ** //

        // Snap radius.
        private var toleRance:int = 20

        // Mouse offset.
        private var offx:Number = 0;
        private var offy:Number = 0;

        // Dragged object.
        private var TheDrag:Sprite;

        private function startDragging(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Get the dragged object reference.
            TheDrag = e.target as Sprite;

            trace("Try dragging:", TheDrag, TheDrag.name);

            if (TheDrag.name != "Circa") return;

            // Bring it to front.
            setChildIndex(TheDrag, numChildren - 1);

            // Record the mouse offset. If you comment the next 2 lines
            // the object will just snap to mouse by its center.
            offx = TheDrag.x - mouseX;
            offy = TheDrag.y - mouseY;

            // Watch the object position every frame.
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

            // Subscribe for certain events that mean the end of dragging.
            stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, stopDragging);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
        }

        private function onFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            // Get new object (x,y) according to the mouse position.
            var aPos:Point = new Point;

            aPos.x = mouseX + offx;
            aPos.y = mouseY + offy;

            // Browse through the list of snap points.
            for (var i:int = 0; i < Dots.length; i++)
            {
                // Snap to a point within tolerance pixels radius.
                if (Point.distance(aPos, Dots[i]) < toleRance)
                {
                    aPos = Dots[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            TheDrag.x = aPos.x;
            TheDrag.y = aPos.y;
        }

        private function stopDragging(e:Event):void
        {
            TheDrag = null;

            // Stop monitoring.
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

            // Stop waiting for events to cancel dragging.
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, stopDragging);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Organis thanks for the information. I have a better understanding of it now. However the issue is still persistent. the trace states that I am clicking on the mcOptions and not the MovieClips nested in the mcOptions. Changing to Target instead of currentTarget does nothing. This works of course startScreen.mcOptions.mcPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTap);  But I dont want to have to do that to all the Buttons, way too much listeners.

Comment: @Nathan I've posted an update, I hope it will help you figure how it **should** work and figure out the mistakes.